# Why Doesn't This JQuery Function Work? (Making Navbar Transparent When Scrolling Down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been following a tutorial. I was unable to figure out why none of my JQuery functions work. I scrolled down and nothing happens. All of my files are properly linked and referenced. I tried to change the javascript so scrolling 50px will change the opacity but it still did not work. Please help!

Thanks for your time.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-mmgLkCYLUQbXn0B1SRqzHar6dCnv9oZFPEC1g1cwlkk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="css/mobile.css.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="css/widescreen.css">

    <title>EdgeLedger Financial | Accounting & Investment</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="logo">
            <span class="text-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Edge
            </span>Ledger
        </h1>

        <ul>
            <li class="a" href="#"><a>Home</a></li>
            <li class="a" href="#"><a>What</a></li>
            <li class="a" href="#"><a>Who</a></li>
            <li class="a" href="#"><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <!-- Showcase-->

<header id="showcase">
    <div class="showcase-content">
        <h1 class="l-heading">
            The Sky Is The Limit
        </h1>
        <p class="lead">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, quidem nostrum blanditiis eaque voluptatum dignissimos?
        </p>
        <a href="" id="what" class="btn">Read More</a>

    </div>
</header>    

<!-- Section: What We Do-->
<section id="what" class="bg-light py-1">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="m-heading text-center"><span class="text-primary">What</span> We Do</h2>

        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <i class="fas fa-university fa-2x"></i>
                <div>
                   <h3>Investment Banking</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto ex eius sed? Eius, accusamus nobis!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-2x"></i>
                <div>
                   <h3>Portfolio Management</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto ex eius sed? Eius, accusamus nobis!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-2x"></i>
                <div>
                   <h3>Tax & Custodial</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto ex eius sed? Eius, accusamus nobis!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Section: Who We are-->
<section id="who">
    <div class="who-img"></div>
    <div class="who-text bg-dark p-2">
        <h2 class="m-heading"><span class="text-primary">Who</span> We Are </h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium sapiente fugiat ab minus, sunt amet itaque id cupiditate inventore tempora.</p>
        <h3>Our Team</h3>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Mark Smith: CEO</li>
            <li>Shannon Johnson: CFO</li>
            <li>John Corbit: Lead Accountant</li>
            <li>Janet Williams: Investment Manager</li>
            <li>Kara Jackson: Senior Accountant</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Section: Clients-->
<section id="clients" class="py-1">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="m-heading text-center">
            <span class="text-primary">Our</span>
            Clients
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="items py1">
        <div><img src="./img/logos/logo1.png" alt="Client"></div>
        <div><img src="./img/logos/logo2.png" alt="Client"></div>
        <div><img src="./img/logos/logo3.png" alt="Client"></div>
        <div><img src="./img/logos/logo4.png" alt="Client"></div>
        <div><img src="./img/logos/logo5.png" alt="Client"></div>
    </div>

</section>

<!-- Section: Contact-->
<section id="contact">
    <div class="contact-form bg-primary p-2">
        <h2 class="m-heading">Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Please use the form below to contact us</p>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="name" id="name" width="100%" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-dark">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="map">

    </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="main-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 EdgeLedger All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>

</footer>

<!-- JQuery CDN -->
<script 
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<!-- Local JS File -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Google Maps -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWwjIowcgGZxjQzSS1VlE_PtwSPrN0XJs&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Robot');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roberty', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

p {
    margin: 0.75rem 0;
}

/*Utility Classes */

.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.text-primary {
    color: #93cb52;
}

.bg-light {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    color: #333;
}

.bg-dark {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-primary {
    background: #93cb52;
    color: #fff;
}

.l-heading {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.m-heading {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.lead {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.py-1 { padding: 1.5rem 0; }
.py-2 { padding: 2rem 0; }
.py-3 { padding: 3rem 0; }

.p-1 { padding: 1.5rem; }
.p-2 { padding: 2rem; }
.p-3 { padding: 3rem; }

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #93cb52;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-dark {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: #7ab436;
}

.list {
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.list li {
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    border-bottom: #444 dotted 1px;
}

/*Navbar */

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    background: #93cb52;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
    background: #333 url('../img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
}

#showcase .showcase-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    /* Overlay */
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* Section: What We Do*/

#what .items {
    display: flex;
    padding:1rem;
}

#what items .item {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem; 
}

#what .items .item i {
    background: #93cb52;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Section: Who We Are*/

#who {
    display: flex;
}

#who div {
    flex: 1;
}

#who .who-img {
    background: url('../img/people.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

/* Section Clients */
#clients .items {
    display: flex;
}

#clients .items img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto; 
    width: 60%;
}

/* Section: Contact */

#contact {
    display: flex;
}

#contact .map, #contact .contact-form {
    flex: 1;
}

#contact .contact-form .form-group {
    margin: 0.75rem;
}

#contact .contact-form label {
    display: block;
}

#contact .contact-form input,
#contact .contact-form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5;
}
```

main.js

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    const loc = { lat: 42.361145, lng: -71.057083 };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('.map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: loc
    });

    const marker = new google.maps. Marker({position: loc, map: map});
}

// Sticky menu background

window.addEventListener ('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 150) {
        document.querySelector('#navbar')style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#navbar').style.opacity = 1;
    }
});

// Smooth Scrolling

$('#navbar a, .btn').on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== '') {
      event.preventDefault();

      const hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
        },
        800
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: have you looked in the browser developer console to see if there are any errors? - for example, the missing `.` in `document.querySelector('#navbar')style.opacity = 0.2;` will make your code not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dot missing in this line:

```
document.querySelector('#navbar')style.opacity = 0.2;
```

(before "style")